# Exclude filename and only search text in grep

Tags: ubuntu, unix, grep

I would like to search for the term "Liszt" within the contents of all text files *except* their file name. So if there was a file called `Liszt Mazeppa.txt` it should not be matched as the term "Liszt" is in the file name.

Conversely if there were a file called "Masur LGO.txt" whose contents were `Beethoven 3; Liszt Orpheus` this *should* be matched.

I would not use find as from how I understand it find is used for searching for file names.

I tried:
`grep -TiPr --include="*.txt" "Liszt" >  ./ matches.txt`

Unfortunately this still matches text files which have the word Liszt in them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the filenames of the files containing the word `Liszt`

```
find . -type f ! -name '*Liszt*' -exec grep -lw Liszt {} \;
```

#### edit

Your rewritten question does not add much.
If you really don't care about the filenames you can remove the `-name` condition from the previous `find`.

Consider what you want when a file whose name contains `Liszt` also has `Liszt` in its content.

Comment: I've re-written question. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score -1):

Regarding `I would not use find as from how I understand it find is used for searching for file names.` - your use of GNU `grep`'s messy options to both find files and search within files is confusing you.

Don't use `grep` to **find** files, there's a perfectly good tool to **find** files with a very obvious name, `find`. The GNU guys really messed up when they gave GNU grep `-r` and all those other options for finding files thereby giving people the possibility of making `grep` commands unnecessarily convoluted.

Finding files and searching within files are 2 conceptually separate things so use `find` to **find** files and then `grep` to **g/re/p** (Globally match a Regular Expression and Print the result) within files.

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec grep -HTi 'Liszt' {} +
```

I'm just guessing at the `grep` options you'll want from reading your existing code since you didn't provide any expected output.

Comment: The expected output would be the filenames with the lines that match. So from what I understand what you've written grep never matches file name - only the contents of text file, right?

Output would be something like:
```\home\kanishk\Masur LGO.txt - Liszt Orpheus
\home\kanishk\Karajan.txt - Liszt Mazeppa```

Comment: Right, try running it see.